# MySQL node.js returning correct value but rest of code working differently

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I've been using mysql to access my database however, although it works kind of, the rest of the code seems to execute asynchronously, e.g.

```
con.connect(function(err) {});

function checkIfUserExists(username) {
  con.query("SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE username = ?", username, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (result.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

if I log `result.length` before the if statement I get the right length however no matter what the function will always return false.

or for example

```
con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return result[0].UserID;
  });
```

this is used within a function to get a certain userid and when logged, `result[0].UserID` logs the correct userid but it doesn't return any value

I'm not too sure what I'm missing about mysql but I'm not very sure on how to fix this

Comment: Did you forget to return ? `return con.query...` ?

Comment: Returning from in callbacks does nothing. Your `result.length > 0` check and returning true/false is complete useless. You are mixing synchron and asynchron code.

Comment: If all you care about is the presence of a row, consider `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead and compare the result. You don't need the data, so don't fetch it.